# Кэширование изображений на стороне сервера

Tags: php, сервер, кэширование

Добрый день. Подскажите, как можно кэшировать на стороне сервера все изображения на конкретной странице.    Есть новостная лента, которая отображает новости (с фото) с поддоменов сайта. Получается очень много `get` запросов и большая нагрузка на сервер.     Каким образом можно закэшировать изображения на стороне сервера?    p.s. нагуглить пока не удалось, кругом или кэш на стороне клиента или сохранение целиком страницы, мне это не подходит.   Доступа к самому серверу нет. Все сжатия включены.    Если что, в htaccess вкл.:

```
# Enable expiration control 
ExpiresActive On 
# Default expiration: 1 hour after request 
ExpiresDefault "now plus 1 hour" 

# Image files expiration: 1 month after request 
ExpiresByType image/bmp "now plus 1 month"     
ExpiresByType image/gif "now plus 1 month"   
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "now plus 1 month"   
ExpiresByType image/jpg "now plus 1 month"   
ExpiresByType image/jp2 "now plus 1 month"   
ExpiresByType image/pipeg "now plus 1 month"   
ExpiresByType image/png "now plus 1 month"   
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "now plus 1 month"   
ExpiresByType image/tiff "now plus 1 month"   
ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon "now plus 1 month"   
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "now plus 1 month"   
ExpiresByType image/ico "now plus 1 month"   
ExpiresByType image/icon "now plus 1 month"   
ExpiresByType text/ico "now plus 1 month"   
ExpiresByType application/ico "now plus 1 month"   
ExpiresByType image/vnd.wap.wbmp "now plus 1 month"   
ExpiresByType application/vnd.wap.wbxml "now plus 1 month"
```

Comment: если у вас `<img src="..."` то от get-запросов вы никак не избавитесь. Вопрос в том, как отдаются эти изображения. Это просто доступ к файлу  изображения на сервере? Если да, то обрезан ли файл до нужных размеров, чтобы минимизировать трафик? Если нет, то что делают скрипты при подготовке изображения. Вы вряд ли уменьшите число запросов, но можете повысить их эффективность. и про какой сервер вообще речь то хоть напишите. а то начнут писать про nginx а у вас iis

Comment: да - <img src="...",  файлы обрезаны (вес +/- 300 кб). По сути я понял, что кэш тут не поможет видимо. Но разгрузить процессор как-то надо. К серверу доступа нет.